# Type 'R[P]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'

Tags: typescript, redux, reselect

I'm trying to integrate reselect and redux with typescript. I'm exporting types of reducers. Here's what my type looks like.

```
type Reducers = {
    user: Reducer<{
        isLogged: boolean;
        isLogging: boolean;
        isFinished: boolean;
        response: {
            idToken: string;
            sessionState: string;
            accessToken: string;
            refreshToken: string;
            tokenType: string;
            scope: string;
            profile: {
                ...;
```

I would like to convert it to something like this

```
State = {
    user: {
        isLogged: boolean;
        isLogging: boolean;
        isFinished: boolean;
        response: {
            idToken: string;
            sessionState: string;
            accessToken: string;
            refreshToken: string;
            tokenType: string;
            scope: string;
            profile: {
                ...;
```

And here's how I'm doing it successfully but I get typescript error. I believe that's because ReturnType should be used with arrow function like `ReturnType<() => R[P]>` but that does not give me result I want

```
export type CreateState<R> = {
  [P in keyof R]: ReturnType<R[P]>
}
type State = CreateState<Reducers>
```

[typescript error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7CMW.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can make it more generic without any extra types:

```js
export type CreateState<R> = {
    [P in keyof R]: R[P] extends (...args: any) => any ? ReturnType<R[P]> : never
}
```